# install pybrains on miniconda

Tags: python, anaconda, pybrain, miniconda

How can I install pybrain into miniconda? Here is what I try with clean miniconda install:

```
C:\Miniconda3_64\Scripts>conda install -c ideas pybrain
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: ....

The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pybrain
  - python 3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: `conda install -c mq pybrain=0.3.3`

Comment: @cel please post as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Comment: feel free to use my comment as a template for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conda install -c mq pybrain=0.3.3

does it.